# How does SpeechSynthesis return a chosen list of languages?

Tags: javascript, speech-to-text, speech-synthesis

Good Morning everybody,

I am still working on a questionnaire for illiterate people. For that I am using a Text to Speech application (thanks to @JO3-W3B-D3V)

The Problem is that the questionnaire will be developped in several languages, which means, that the text to speech application has to support several languages as well.

```
SpeechSynthesis.getVoices()
```

If I understood it correctly, the function above returns a list of all objects representing all the available voices on the current device. Now to my questions:

1. Is there a way to return a selection of these languages? For example, the listshould not return all 15 languages which are available on the device, but only 4 chosen ones?
2. Is there a way to add more languages to the device? I am using Chrome. If I understood it correctly Chromes gets the languages from Microsoft and Google. Therefore Chrome should display new  language-option if I add a new language to my operation system (Windows 10). Is that assupmtion correct? I am asking because I did that already and nothing changed, so I might be missing something.

Hope my questions make sense :)

Have a great day!

Answer (score 1):

## Explained

Okay, so I'll answer this in two parts, considering the fact that you've *kinda* asked two questions, both are relatively simple & straightforward thankfully.

### Question One

You've asked how to get `_` chosen languages that you'd like to support, well that's simple, it's as easy as manipulating an array, within my example I've used the [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) function, fairly straightforward stuff.

**P.S.** For the sake of some form of consistence, I've written this snippet in a **very** similar fashion to the one that I wrote in the [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54535468/text-to-speech-of-highlighted-text/54537807) that you asked regarding `speechSynthesis`.

#### Assumptions

As stated within the code comments, I've written this snippet in such a way that there's no duplicated entries, i.e. within the snippet below, you will end up with a list that only contains one entity that supports the English language. In other words, you won't have both `en-GB` & `en-US`, of course you can change this, I just *assumed* that you'd want this type of feature, of course this is down to you & your requirements entirely.

```js
// IIFE for the sake of it. 
(function() {
  "use strict";

  // This is a simple list of languages that you wish to support. 
  var supportedLanguages = ['en', 'de', 'es', 'fr'];
  var languages = [];

  // This is essentially similar to jQuery's $.ready.
  var ready = function(callback) {
    var d = document,
      s = d.readyState;

    // DOMContentLoaded was fired
    if (s == "complete" || s == "loaded" || s == "interactive") {
      callback();
    } else {
      if (d.addEventListener) {
        d.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", callback, false);
      } else {
        d.attachEvent("onDOMContentLoaded", callback);
      }
    }
  };

  // This is just a simple function to process whether or not you'd like to
  // push a voice onto the array or not.
  var shouldPush = function(array, object) {
    var language = object.lang || '';
    var snipped = language.substring(0, 2);

    // Generate a list of all of the known languages. 
    var languageList = array.map(function(object) {
      return object.lang;
    });

    // Create a list of short hand language names.
    var snippedList = languageList.map(function(language) {
      return language.substring(0, 2);
    });

    // Save having a bloated if statement, personally I find this 
    // more readable. 
    //
    // Only push relevant ones, saves having any duplicated entities, i.e. 
    // this will not allow for both en-US & en-GB to be among the list,
    // this can be altered, this is merely based on an assumption that you 
    // wouldn't want both en-US & en-GB, etc. 
    var isToPush = !snippedList.includes(snipped) &&
      !languageList.includes(language) &&
      supportedLanguages.includes(snipped);

    // If true, push to array.
    if (isToPush) {
      array.push(object);
    }

    // Then of course return the array object. 
    return array;
  };

  // This is essentially the list of voices that you've picked to support.
  var getSelectedLanguages = function() {
    languages = speechSynthesis.getVoices().reduce(shouldPush, []);
  };

  // A starting point for this snippet.
  var start = function() {
    speechSynthesis.onvoiceschanged = function() {
      getSelectedLanguages();
      console.log(languages);
    };
  };

  // Run the code when ready.
  ready(start);
})();
```

### Question Two

I'm not entirely sure if there's a "clean & easy" way to do this, having conducted my own research on the matter I've found that it **looks** like this would require some form of tinkering. One of the *better* sources of information that I've found is [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47379725/how-do-i-add-a-voice-language-to-speechsynthesis).

Having further looked into this question, it looks like [`Artyom`](https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/534/how-to-add-a-language-that-is-not-totally-supported-by-artyom-js) also suggests that there's no simple way to achieve this, it **looks** like you can only add a language by installing the language into the operating system, so I'm lead to believe.

#### Conclusion

One **possible** idea is that you ***could***, and I emphasise the word **could** possibly do this via implementing an API of your own, **however** I can't imagine this would be a **solid or reliable** implementation, as my conclusion is based on research suggests in order for an additional language to be included, the **user** is somewhat responsible for that, as it **looks** like it needs the user to have `_` language installed on their OS in order for `speechSynthesis` to make use of `_` language.

I actually find it a little odd that it appears that there's little/no *formal* documentation on this subject, rather I've just found mostly informal documentation, suggestions and assumptions. This could however be down to my lack of investigation, bear in mind that I've spent ~15 minutes at most looking into this issue.

#### Sources

1. [A link to flaviocopes.com regarding `speechSynthesis`.](https://flaviocopes.com/speech-synthesis-api/#cross-browser-implementation-to-get-the-language)
2. [A link to Artyom.js, a library for speech related APIs.](https://sdkcarlos.github.io/sites/artyom.html)
3. [A link to a previous stack overflow question similar to the second part of this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41549950/speech-synthesis-api-supported-languages)
4. [A link to a medium article.](https://towardsdatascience.com/speech-synthesis-as-a-service-5c65d17e62f4)
5. [MDN documentation.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SpeechSynthesis)
6. [A treehouse blog post.](https://blog.teamtreehouse.com/getting-started-speech-synthesis-api)

---

While I may not have the answer that you desire for your second question, I hope that this entire answer has helped in some form or another! :)

Comment: Thank you first of all. You confirmed als my thought, that there is a lack of information regarding my second question. I am still struggling abit regarding the code. Do I have to use it additionally to the one you provided in my first question? I also tried merging both codes but once again my lack of skill in not helping.

Comment: @InPanic Could you show me what you've done or what you're trying to do and I'll just made a JSFiddle or something?